# Conversion of char array to String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to java.How to convert char array into string array.My char array holds the values from Resultset rs.The code for char array is

```
char[] time= rs.getString(logtime).toCharArray();
```

How to convert this time into String array.

Comment: is it really an array of Strings you want, and not a String?

Comment: yes I want an array of Strings not a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. Assuming that you want a string array with the same contents as the character array (one character per string), here's a very quick and dirty solution:

```
char[] time = rs.getString(logtime).toCharArray();
String[] s = (new String(time)).split("(?<=.)");
```

Or, if you don't really need to convert to a `char` array first, you could just simply do:

```
String[] s = rs.getString(logtime).split("(?<=.)");
```

The regular expression used for the `split` method is a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion to match any character.

---

A cleaner (and most likely more efficient) solution would look as follows:

```
char[] time = rs.getString(logtime).toCharArray();
String[] s = new String[time.length];
for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    s[i] = String.valueOf(time[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why would he create a new String and then split it again, when the only thing he needs is a conversion?

Comment: @KaterinaA. I clearly stated that it was a very quick and dirty solution. I'll update to include a cleaner solution as well.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen when i run this code an error comes that "The result set has no current row".I tried doing char[] time = rs.getString(1).toCharArray();.But then also error persists.Help me.

Comment: Did you call rs.next() first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 char[] time= rs.getString(logtime).toCharArray();
 String[] timeStr = new String[time.length];
 for (int i=0,len=time.length; i<len; i++){
     timeStr[i] = String.valueOf(time[i]);
 }
```